# Double body tag causes Wordpress site not working properly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, tags

Well, I have strange issue. Most of Wordpress sites hosted on BlueHost have double  tag when the HTML code has only one. Having double  tag causes issues with Wordpress sites to be rendered properly (CSS is not triggered) or have overall functional issues (broken layout, menu etc).

Example: [image: double body tag]

rendered site: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d62g32l26

and site URL: http://www.rosefiore.com/

> header.php: http://pastebin.com/pvgLfwGb footer.php:
>   http://pastebin.com/iehsX77B index.php: http://pastebin.com/3BVE1U4V

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: There's no double `<body>` when I view the source of the site and it seems to work properly... Did you rule out any plugin/theme issues?

Comment: No plugin or theme issue. Use Inspect Element and you will see double body tags (screenshot above).

Comment: I used View Source to view the actual code that's being rendered. Inspecting also shows only one tag. Ain't a browser extension?

Comment: View Source comes with one body tag but rendered part (Inspect Element) is not. And no matter what browser - FireFox or Chrome

Comment: Was the issue already fixed? I, like b__, saw no duplicate body tag on either the source or the rendered version. It sounds like something on your end. You mentioned 28 BH sites of yours have a double body tag yet you'll notice there hasn't been a massive uproar of complaints from BlueHost users.

Comment: No, nothing was fixed. I have here 10 computers with same result. Switching IPS doesn't help. Even tested from home - same result (screenshot above).

Comment: Also just checked those sites on Mac and Ubuntu - here all of them works fine, but what can cause rendering issues on multiple Windows computers and locations?

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like our BlueHost account got hacked and each WP installation got code injection into wp-config.php file which looks like http://pastebin.com/zbVFcUHZ

For me it looks like server level hack because all wp-config files were "infected" at exact same time, some of those sites were behind .htaccess password protection and WP engine prevents write to that file when WP is already installed.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so the question is "closed".

Answer (score 0):

"Most of Wordpress sites hosted on BlueHost have double tag when the HTML code has only one."

Absolutely not. Where did you get this idea?

There are many reasons you could have a double body tag. Can you paste what you feel are relevant snippets from index.php, header.php, and footer.php inside your theme folder. I'll update my answer accordingly upon seeing these.

Comment: "Most of Wordpress sites hosted on BlueHost have double tag when the HTML code has only one." - I have 30 sites there and after weekend 28 of them got double body tag issue.

Comment: OP updated with links to PasteBing and requested files