# Wordpress pages on site all have double body tag

Tags: css, wordpress

All the WordPress sites I have hosted on the same box are generating an extra body tag when viewed in-browser. Viewing source shows that it should only have the one body tag but then when I actually view the page it has two.

It appears to be happening on almost all the sites I currently have hosted, and one of the few sites it wasn't happening to that was fine this morning, has also changed to have the same issue. I've tried viewing it in multiple browsers and the same issue is seen. Also occurs regardless of whether I'm logged into admin or not. Happens on both the main site as well as the admin backend.

What I'm currently seeing:

```
<script src="/google_analytics_auto.js"></script></head>
<body class=" customize-support"><body>

<div id="wrapper" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div id="header">
```

What I see when viewing-source:

```
<script src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script></head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
```

If you Inspect Element on http://michaeldebevec.com/ and then view-source you will be able to see this happening. If you view http://michaeldebevec.com/wp-admin/ you can see the change of layout this is causing compared to what the default WordPress login looks like.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with one your plugins which you must be using on all your sites.

Comment: After deactivating all the plugins and changing the theme to the Twenty Twelve theme the problem still remains.

Comment: i think you have don't closed </body> tag. if u use mozilla FF browser press ctrl + U and will see red marked tags. Html after render close tags autocratically but its wrong, check u layout

Comment: @Dreamm, the `<body>` tag is clearly closed...That's not the issue

Comment: Can you provide some source code from `header.php` and/or, `footer.php`... `page.php` in the theme files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double body tag causes Wordpress site not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228660/double-body-tag-causes-wordpress-site-not-working-properly)

Comment: Yeah I saw that question Hidden Hobbes but there wasn't an answer provided that I could replicate. From the looks of it all the different templates all have massive chunks of code injected into the start of some of the template files.

Comment: Appears to be a big block of code added to every config, index, function, and header file in the WP install. Going through to erase it all then upload those files and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

So it's caused by some sort of code injection that has happened to the files. The solution was to download locally all the files off the server and run a search looking for the following string that was found at the end of the injection:

```
==');?>
```

I found it had infected all my header, config, index and functions files. After locating all the infected files you go through and erase the injected code and re-save. Upload the new files back to the server and as far as I'm aware that solves it.